# Cannot install pycrypto inside virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, pycrypto

I tried `pip install pycrypto` using the virtualenv pip.

When I'm using `sudo` the installation succeeds, but not inside the virtual environment which does not help me.

The `sudo apt-get install python-dev` solution didn't help either. And also using `easy_install` and `yum` didn't help.

This is the bottom line of the error i get when I'm trying to install:

```
Command /home/ubuntu/conceep-env/bin/python -c "import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='/home/ubuntu/conceep-env/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/tmp/pip-NaKMgy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/conceep-env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/ubuntu/conceep-env/build/pycrypto
Storing debug log for failure in /var/tmp/tmp3k2sTZ
```

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed it using `sudo path/to/my/virtenv/bin/pip install pycrypto`.

Comment: But for pycrypto you need to install also "python3-dev python-dev"